# Android change chart color from white to red but just 30%

Tags: android, android-layout

CODE:

```
public final void SetBitmapImage(Bitmap paramBitmap, int color, float percentage)
  {
    float f = percentage * -360.0F;        
    int i = paramBitmap.getWidth();
    int j = paramBitmap.getHeight();
    Paint localPaint1 = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint localPaint2 = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint localPaint3 = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Bitmap localBitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(i, j, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas localCanvas1 = new Canvas(localBitmap1);
    localCanvas1.rotate(-90.0F, i / 2.0F, j / 2.0F);
    RectF localRectF = new RectF(0.0F, 0.0F, i, j);
    localPaint1.setStrokeWidth(2.0F);
    localPaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    localPaint2.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    Bitmap localBitmap2 = paramBitmap; // this should include color I think but don't know how
    localCanvas1.drawArc(localRectF, 0.0F, f, true, localPaint1);
    Bitmap localBitmap3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(localBitmap1.getWidth(), localBitmap1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas localCanvas2 = new Canvas(localBitmap3);
    localCanvas2.drawBitmap(paramBitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, localPaint3);
    localCanvas2.drawBitmap(localBitmap1, 0.0F, 0.0F, localPaint2);
    Bitmap localBitmap4 = Bitmap.createBitmap(localBitmap2.getWidth(), localBitmap2.getHeight(), localBitmap2.getConfig());
    Canvas localCanvas3 = new Canvas(localBitmap4);
    localCanvas3.drawBitmap(localBitmap2, new Matrix(), null);
    localCanvas3.drawBitmap(localBitmap3, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
    localBitmap2.recycle();
    localBitmap3.recycle();
    localBitmap1.recycle();
    setImageBitmap(localBitmap4);
  }
```

but the image is still the same. I want that 70% of image stay white, 30% red.

I think that a problem is with `Bitmap localBitmap2`.

```
Bitmap localBitmap2 = paramBitmap; // this should include color I think but don't know how
```

Should be something like:

```
Bitmap localBitmap2 = Something(paramBitmap, color); which will set the color
```

Comment: I have checked everything but I can not find the solution. I don't need gradient effect

Comment: what type of chart are you using - bar/pie?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731261/android-draw-circle-with-2-colors-pie-chart

Answer (score 1):

In android, when you set a hex code, the first 6 digits following the # is the normal code, and there is an optional 2 digits after for transparency.

```
#000000 = black
#00000000 = fully transparent
```

Given that that last two digits need to be in hex format, you need to choose your range between 0 - 255, then convert it back to hex.

TIP: You can do this using windows calculator in 'programmer' mode. :)

Examples:

30% opacity: 255*0.70 = 178. 178 converted to hex = B2.

So add B2 to the end of whatever color code you have, and it will be 30% opaque.

```
#000000B2
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Can you give me an example?