# is it possible to draw a two layer Pie Chart?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

Hi i am trying to implement a chart like the following. Please see the image and help me find a suitable solution for this. Here i am using  [MPAndroidChart Library.](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

[image]

Right now my pie chart is look like below image.

[image]

> I am using below xml

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> And in java, i have manage angle like that.

```
mChart.setMaxAngle(270f); // HALF CHART
mChart.setRotationAngle(135f);
```

I still have not been able to create the inner line of the pie chart. I want the graph that I already mention on top. How can I draw that line?

Comment: have you seen this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731261/android-draw-circle-with-2-colors-pie-chart

Comment: @Dilip yes i go through with this chart but unable to implement, because this is code of two separate circle which based upon the circle. But my problem i think you can see into image what i want to achieve? Please hit up for getting answer soon.

Comment: You can achieve that by taking 2 pie charts with same centre point and different sizes of them. @APKAPPS

Comment: @DwlRathod I try this but it's not happening because pie-chart has multiple values with white background. Means the main pie-chart is hidden behind the small pie chart

Comment: I have made an example with [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) lib and it's working fine. @APKAPPS

Comment: Will you please share your answer @DwlRathod

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to add [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library in you project. Here is the basic code I have written, you need to make changes according to your use.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.devdwl.stackdemo;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.PercentFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PieChart mChartOuter, mChartInner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mChartOuter = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.mChartOuter);
        mChartInner = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.mChartInner);

        mChartOuter.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChartInner.getDescription().setEnabled(false);


        mChartOuter.setCenterTextSize(10f);
        mChartInner.setCenterTextSize(10f);

        mChartOuter.setHoleRadius(75f);
        mChartInner.setHoleRadius(75f);

        mChartOuter.setTransparentCircleRadius(50f);
        mChartInner.setTransparentCircleRadius(50f);

        mChartOuter.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        mChartInner.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        setData();

    }

    private void setData() {

        ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            entries.add(new PieEntry((float) ((Math.random() * (float) 5) + (float) 5 / 5), i));
        }

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "Election Results");

        dataSet.setDrawIcons(false);

        dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
        dataSet.setIconsOffset(new MPPointF(0, 40));
        dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

        dataSet.setColors(colors);

        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
        data.setValueTextSize(11f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChartOuter.setData(data);
        mChartInner.setData(data);

        mChartOuter.highlightValues(null);
        mChartInner.highlightValues(null);

        mChartOuter.invalidate();
        mChartInner.invalidate();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/mChartOuter"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/mChartInner"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result

[image]

Good Luck.

Comment: ok thank you let me try and will come back soon with feedback

Comment: thanks something batter than nothing it's worked for me