# Animating a pie chart in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, pie-chart

I want to make a circle in a color, say red. And overtime that red makes way for another color, say blue. Unfortunately, I'm no native English speaker, so I don't really know how to explain it :) I do have created a rough mockup though. ([imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJpGd.jpg)).

I have seen an answer here on SO on creating a pie chart ([stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397192/draw-pie-chart-in-android)).

So my question is basically: how do you animate this properly so that the movements appear fluidly? Isn't redrawing it 60 times a second too resource intensive?

Thanks in advance,

Antarion

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried?  I see you have done research - great!  Anything to show? 60 FPS is perhaps overkill.

Comment: You are right, maybe 60 _is_ overkill. I haven't started coding yet, but I was just wondering if there is some way to not have to redraw the whole image.

Answer (score 0):

it's an example project which have circular chart and according to your need its shows different colors at different values.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803431/4140431

0% red

1%-99% blue

100% green