# How to draw progressive doughnut chart in android using achartengine?

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to design progressive doughnut chart. I have a problem like I am getting doughnut chart but not progressive.
Is it possible to design progressive doughnut chart using achartengine? If it is possible how to do? please anyone can help?

```
DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);
    renderer.setScale((float)1.3);
    renderer.setShowLabels(false);
    renderer.setStartAngle(270);
    //renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(222, 222, 200));
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
    return ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartView(MainActivity.this,
            buildMultipleCategoryDataset("Project budget", titles1, values),
            renderer);
}

private MultipleCategorySeries buildMultipleCategoryDataset(String title,
        List<String[]> titles1, List<Float> values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MultipleCategorySeries series = new MultipleCategorySeries(title);
    int k = 0;
    for (Float value : values) {
       series.add(title, titles1.get(k), values);
        k++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this chart in one of my application which requires real time battery value tracking and showing using doughnut chart. so, i created an example project for this.

[Demo Doughnut Chart](https://github.com/asimiqbalmalik/DemoDoughnutChartWithTextInside)

just download/import this example to your workspace and run.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir,                                                                                           but i want  show two colors at time. for example ..we feeding to some different types of birds, total food is 10kg ,consumed feeding is 7kg for one kind of birds.and for 15 kg its feed (consumed)10 kg to other kind.like that that chart has 4 types. means totally 8 colors,for that i need to implement progressive doughnut chart.thanks in advance.

Comment: without using seek bar is it possible to implement progressive doughnut chart?

Comment: yes,it is possible.only used seek bar for demo purpose..i'm using bluetooth connectivity for receiving values.you can use anytime when you have values during your program execution.