# Can I assign a different radius for each pie slice(like reduce a each pie slice arc surface) using Mp Android API or without using 3rd party api?

Tags: android

Exactly like this image [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk5JC.png]

I tried without using Third Party API Android Canvas (DrawArc() using RectF Param) but not exactly this img

Comment: Have you done any efforts so far? Any code to share with us?

Comment: You can edit your question and put the formatted code and any other relevant information that will make people help you faster by understanding your issue better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397192/draw-pie-chart-in-android ; and this code RectF rectfone = new RectF (125, 100, 800, 800);RectF rectftwo = new RectF (150, 100, 800, 800);
        RectF rectfthree = new RectF (175, 100, 800, 800); added inside MyGraphview after  RectF code,,,,,,,,,,,,and inside onDraw method i added this code inside for loop  if(i==1){canvas.drawArc(rectfone,temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);}if(i==2){canvas.drawArc(rectftwo,temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);}if(i==3){canvas.drawArc(rectfthree,temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;